# How can I Instantiate interdependent lists of Beans in Spring using YML and Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to create a flexible framework for creating components with as much configuration externalized as possible.  I'd like to be able to use the YML configuration to define a collection of beans and use them in another collection of beans.

I'm starting with an application.yml like this:

```
component:
  services:
    - name: google
      url: google.com
    - name: yahoo
      url: yahoo.com
  capabilities:
    - name: searchTehWebsForDragons
      service: google
      inputString: "dragons"
    - name: searchTehWebsForPuppies
      service: google
      inputString: "puppies"
```

I've been able to use the @ConfigurationProperties annotation to parse that into POJOs

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "component")
public class ConfigureComponents{
    public List<Service> services;
    public List<Capability> capabilities;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The Service and Capability classes look like this:

```
public class Service {
    public String name;
    public String url;
    
    public String callIt(String inputString){
        //servicelogic
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Capabilities {
    public String name;
    public Service service;
    public String inputString;

    public String doIt(){
        service.callIt(inputString);
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

So, by default, the YML configuration can create POJOs of the Service objects, but not beans.  I can turn those into beans with something like this:

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    for (Service service: services) (
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(service.name, service);
    )
}
```

But if I'm trying to create the Capability POJOs with the yml, they need to be able to wire in those Service beans.  I've tried getBeans from the context, but they don't seem to exist when I need them.

There have been many questions like this, but I haven't found a streamlined way to do this without reverting to XML configuration.

I know Spring keeps adding functionality, so if there's anything new I've missed, clue me in!

I'd love to put some annotations in the Configuration class to create the List of beans by default, but I haven't figured out how.  I've messed with @Bean annotations, but I can't figure out how that works with a List of Objects.

Any help would be appreciated!  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you want to turn your `List<Service>` into a bean that can be injected into other `Components`.  This can be accomplished by marking your `ConfigureComponents` as a `@Configuration`, and creating a method to return the `List<Service>` as a `Bean`.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "component")
public class ConfigureComponents{
  public List<Service> services;
  public List<Capability> capabilities;

  @Bean
  public List<Service> getServices() {
    return this.services;
  }

  public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
    this.services = services;
  }
}
```

This logic will create a Bean in your Spring context that is a `List` of `Service` that you can then autowire into your other components.

You can also achieve this by marking your `ConfigureComponents` class as a `Component` and just injecting it into your other Beans, and when you want your Services, calling the getter, like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "component")
public class ConfigureComponents{
  public List<Service> services;
  public List<Capability> capabilities;

  public List<Service> getServices() {
    return this.services;
  }

  public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
    this.services = services;
  }
}
```

Now, you can inject `ConfigureComponents` into your collaborators and call `configureComponents.getServices()` to get back your Services.

Comment: I'd actually like to make the Services objects Beans themselves.  The list is only useful to me as a way for the yml to map an unknown number of beans.  And then I'd like to use those Service Beans as injectable dependencies in the Capability beans if possible.   Thank you for the answer though and I'll see if I can clarify further.

Comment: I think you're going to have a difficult time creating multiple beans of the same type from configuration properties.  If you have two beans of type `Service`, then you would have to qualify them to be able to inject them.  I don't see any way that you would be able to differentiate them by defining them this way.  You will need to create a bean factory to be able to handle this.